# Prove: $\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2\ge\sqrt{3}\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt[4]{\frac{5ab}{c}+4a}}$

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality, rearrangement-inequality, schur-inequality

> Prove that the following inequality :$$\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2\ge\sqrt{3}\left(\sqrt[4]{\frac{5ab}{c}+4a}+\sqrt[4]{\frac{5bc}{a}+4b}+\sqrt[4]{\frac{5ca}{b}+4c}\right)$$ holds for all positive real numbers such that: $abc=1$.

I saw problem on: [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2691637p23366158). I tried to continue Arqady comment:

By Holder $$\sqrt3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{\frac{5ab}{c}+4a}=\sqrt3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{ab(5ab+4ac)}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt3\sqrt[4]{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{ab}\right)^3\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{ab}(5ab+4ac)}\leq(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c)^2.$$
We have: $$\sqrt[4]{ab}+\sqrt[4]{bc}+\sqrt[4]{ca}\le\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$$

The rest is prove the following inequality: $$9\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt[4]{ab}(5ab+4ac)}\leq(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})^5$$
However, it is not true by acountable example. I hope we can find a good solution.

Thank you!

Comment: But my way gives a right inequality, which theoretically we can prove without computer :)

Comment: I am sorry, but What do you mean "my way"?

Comment: In your post you showed my solution.

Comment: Are you Arqady on AoPS?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Can you show the rest solution?

Comment: I have no a nice proof. It's the BW.

Comment: Can anyone show AM-GM solution?

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that $$(a+b+c)^2\geq\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{9a^4b^2(5b^2+4c^2)}.$$
Now, by Holder and Rearrangement we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{9a^4b^2(5b^2+4c^2)}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{9a^2b^2\cdot a(5b^2a+4c^2a)}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt[4]{9(ab+ac+bc)^2(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(5b^2a+4c^2a)}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt[4]{9(ab+ac+bc)^2(a+b+c)\left(4\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)+\frac{4(a+b+c)^3}{27}-abc\right)}.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, $u^2\geq v^2$ and  we need to prove that:
$$(3u)^7\geq9(3v^2)^2(4(9uv^2-3w^3)+4u^3-w^3)$$ or
$$27u^7-4u^3v^4-36uv^6+13v^4w^3\geq0$$ and since by Schur $w^3\geq4uv^2-3u^3,$ it's enough to prove that:
$$27u^7-4u^3v^4-36uv^6+13v^4(4uv^2-3u^3)\geq0$$ or
$$u(u^2-v^2)(27u^4+27u^2v^2-16v^4)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: @Michel Rozenberg: I think you are the best on inequalities, here in MSE.

Comment: @Piquito Thank you, but I don't agree and it's really not relevant.

Comment: @Michel Rozenberg.- «À tout seigneur, tout honneur». It is true what I have said. Besides I added **here in MSE** which can be verified.